# Prevent python to create __pycache__ folder

Tags: python

How can i prevent python of creating `__pycache__` folder?

I want to do this constantly.
I don't want to write a special python command every time one script executed or write some code in every python script

```py
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
```

Is there any way to execute the above script every time a `python filename.py` script is executed?

Thanks in advance,

Chris Pappas

Comment: You can enable the `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` [environment variable](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/200)

Comment: Does [this](https://www.scivision.dev/python-pycache-eliminate/#:~:text=For%20Windows%2C%20set%20environment%20variable%20PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE%20to%201%20.,the%20line%20export%20PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE%3D1%20.) help

Comment: I run two command in terminal: `echo "PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX=\$TMPDIR" >> ~/.bashrc` and `echo "export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1" >> /etc/environment` so now i have to test it (not enough code yet). @jjoa thanks this might help me.